# Filtering multiple values against Google Sheet rows in Zapier using python

Tags: python, google-sheets, zapier

I'm attempting to build a system in Zapier that allows users to enter certain restrictions into a google sheet, then runs potential customers against those restrictions to see if they are disqualified or not. The issue I'm running into is that the restrictions are very complicated. The Google sheet has the following structure:

```
Bank   |   Product |   Bundle |   Restriction Geo |   Restriction Geo 2 |   Restriction Geo Val |   Restriction Type |   Restriction Type Val
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Wells      Savings     Ind,Sp      State                                      NY,CA,NV                General                100%                                                  
JMorg       IRA        Ind         County                  CA                 Solano, Marin           Claims                 3
Goldman    Savings     All         Zip                                        94954,27717,38002       Credit Score           680
Wells      Savings     All         Zip                                        48441                   General                100%
```

This is a simplified version of all the restrictions - in reality, I have

- 30+ Banks (Bank)
- 3 products (Product)
- 3 bundles (Bundle)
- 3 restriction geos (State, County, Zip) (Restriction Geo)
- all the state/count/zips (Restriction Geo 2 is for State when Restriction Geo == County)
- 8 restriction types (Restriction Type)
- multiple different restriction vals for each restriction type (Restriction Type Val). I have certain rules for each restriction e.g. a credit score must be over the value, claims must be under, general restriction means that the customer is simply excluded from that geo at 100% etc.

What my Zap does so far is it catches a webhook with some of the customer info, enriches the data by querying our SQL DB to pull the other fields, then pulls all of the restrictions from the google sheet as line items. What I am working on is python code that then runs the customer attributes against those restrictions to output the banks

```
## input data and map to values
banks = input_data['Banks'].split(',')
prod_type = input_data['Product']
bundle_type = input_data['Bundle'].split(',')
rest_geo = input_data['Restriction_Geo']
rest_geo_2 = input_data['Restriction_Geo_2']
rest_geo_val = input_data['Restriction_Geo_Val']
rest_type = input_data['Restriction_Type']
rest_val = input_data['Restriction_Type_Value']
rows = input_data['rows']

##import possibly needed libraries
import re
import json

## all possible banks
banks = ['Goldman','Wells','JMorg','BA']

## get count of rows
row_count = len(banks)

##initialize lists of unique banks, restriction types and geos
unique_banks = []
for x in banks:
    if x not in unique_banks:
            unique_banks.append(x)

unique_rest_type = []
for y in rest_type:
    if y not in unique_rest_type:
            unique_rest_type.append(y)

unique_geo_type = []
for g in rest_geo:
    if g not in unique_geo_type:
        unique_geo_type.append(g)

##loop through to build restrictions (running into issues here)
restriction = []
for c in unique_banks:
    for u in unique_rest_type:
        for g in unique_geo_type:
            for r in rows:
                if r[0] == unique_banks[c] and r[6] == unique_rest_type[u]:
                    if r[3] == 'County': 

## build list of allowed banks for customer
allowed_banks = []
for bank in banks:
    for r in restriction:
        if bank == r:
            ##do nothing
        else:
            allowed_banks.append(bank)

## just testing what output looks like
output = [{'banks': unique_banks,'carr_len':row_count,'occ_len':row_count_2,'row_1':rows}]
```

The output I am looking for is something that spits out which Banks are restricted for users, and which ones aren't. Ideally, it would be something like

```
output = [{'user_id':user_id,'allowed_banks':allowed_banks,'restricted_banks':restricted_banks,'restrictions':restrictions}]
```

Where restrictions in the output is the customer attribute that was restricted by the banks(s).

I'm def still working through this, and not sure if my use case isn't too hard for Zapier's code module. I'm bogged down in how to run through the multiple criteria to build the restrictions. Additionally, since I can't use pandas or numpy in zapier, I'm not sure if this sort of filtering can be done in basic python. Any help or ideas is appreciated!